# Does parent template's CSS properties applies to extended child template in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I was making a site with Django in which I was applying CSS properties to an extended template file. The CSS file is imported in parent template and is used in child template. But it isn't showing any changes in child template. Here's my code:

```css
.c1 a:hover {
    background-color: #1D1C1C;
    color: white;
}

.theta {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Parent File -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Site</title>

        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        

        <!-- <link href="../static/css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
        <!-- <link href="../static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Site</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">A</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu c1" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">a</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">b</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">B</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script> 
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js' %}"></script>

<!--        <script src="../static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/js/popper.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="../static/js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
 -->
    </body>
</html>

<!-- Child File -->
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="theta">
    {% for i in theta %}
        {{ i }}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<br>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any additional loc required to show those changes in child template?

Answer (score 0):

use this for clear collect static files:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

Comment: So that command will fetch all of my static files and serve it from a single location? For all apps?

Comment: Hi @AnuragSrivastava, I guessed you config your project to collect all static files in one location. But if you set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'run/static')`, all static files on your project collect in `run/static`.

Comment: You have to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` like this: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]`.

Comment: Hey, @MohammadAliAmini aren't those commands are used to set your static path correctly? But the fact is my parent template is showing up the changes done by static files. It is the child template that is extended from parent template not showing any changes.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, right click on child template on browser then click on `View page source`. Can you see your style at the top of page? a thing like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">`, if yes click on it. What do you see?

Comment: Hey @MohammadAliAmini, Thanks man i've got it now. It seems my browser cached up those files and was showing the cached version of the CSS file, clearing up browser cache does the job for me. Thanks a lot.